# Substring extraction from variable length strings with regex python

Tags: python, regex, substring

I have a dataset of texts, from which I am extracting all "sentences" containing a pattern `r'\b' + ' (?:\w+ )?(?:\w+ )?'.join(my_words_markers) + r'\b'`.

I want now to reduce all long "sentences" (> 200 words), to more readable ones, taking, e.g., only 30 words before and after my `pattern`, replacing the trimmed part with "...".

Is there a clean way to do so ?

EDIT : the search is conducted on preprocessed text (lowercasing, removing stop words and punctuation and other selected-by-hand words), then matched sentences are stored in their original form.
I want to operate the trimming on the original sentence (with punctuation and stop words)

EXAMPLE:

```
t1 = "This is a complete sentence, containing colors and other words: pink, blue, yellow, tree and chair, orange, green, hello, world, black, sofa, brown. It will be preprocessed"
t2 = preprocess(t1)  # ---> "complete sentence containing colors words pink blue yellow tree chair orange green hello world black sofa brown preprocessed"
my_words_markers = "yellow orange".split()
pattern = r'\b' + ' (?:\w+ )?(?:\w+ )?'.join(my_words_markers) + r'\b'
match = re.search(pattern, t2, re.I)
if match: list_of_sentences.append(t1)
```

In this `list_of_senteces`, I want to trim the longest ones:

```
# what I want is a trimmed version of t1, with, e.g., 4 words before and after pattern: 
"... other words: pink, blue, yellow, tree and chair, orange, green, hello, world, black ..."
```

Comment: Please post some examples of processed and unprocessed sentences. I don't want to update my answer just to be hit with "thanks but it doesn't work with my data" a 2nd time.

Comment: @Rawing happy now?

Comment: Yes and no. I don't think this is possible...

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your regex so that it also matches up to 30 words before and after the pattern:

```
pattern = r'(?:\w+\W+){,30}\b' + \
          r' (?:\w+ )?(?:\w+ )?'.join(my_words_markers) + \
          r'\b(?:\W+\w+){,30}'
```

Then loop over all sentences, and if the regex matches, use [`match.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.start) and [`match.end()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.end) to check if you have to insert an ellipsis `...`:

```
for sentence in sentences:
    match = re.search(pattern, sentence)
    if match:
        text = '{}{}{}'.format('...' if match.start() > 0 else '',
                               match.group(),
                               '...' if match.end() < len(sentence) else '')
        print(text)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't properly work. I've edited my question

Comment: @Fed Please try to include _all_ of your requirements in the question next time...